# Pentagram Geometry

Tags: geometry

Consider a regular pentagon with vertices (in clockwise order) $A,B,C,D,E$. Let $A '$ be the point of intersection of $BD$
and $CE$, let $B '$ be the point of intersection of $CE$ and $DA$ and so on. If the triangle $AC 'D '$ has area $1$, what is the area of
pentagon $A 'B 'C 'D 'E '$?

I've found a few angles and lengths of sides using trig, but I can't see an answer in sight. Can anyone come with an answer with proof. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In a regular pentagon, the ratio between the length of a diagonal and the length of a side is $\frac{1+\sqrt{5}}{2}=\varphi$. It follows that, if the area of the darker triangle in the picture is $1$, the area of $BED$ is $\varphi^4$ and the area of the dotted triangle is $\varphi^2$.

By a straightforward decomposition, the area of the smaller pentagon is:
$$ \varphi^4 - \varphi^2 - 2 = (3\varphi+2)-(\varphi+1)-2 = 2\varphi-1=\color{red}{\sqrt{5}}.$$

[image]

Comment: Why does it follow that if the area of the darker triangle is $1$ then the area of $BED=\varphi^4$ and the area of the dotted triangle is $\varphi^2$.

Comment: @MadChickenMan: the darker triangle, $BED$ and the dotted triangle are similar triangles. You know the ratios between their sides, so the ratios between their areas.

Comment: Ok thanks, I was mainly confused because I wasn't sure what the ratio of the sides of the darker triangle was to the sides of the other triangles as there was no expression for its side length. I said $DC '=x$ and $BD '=y$ though and so $x+y=d$, where $d$ is the diagonal length and so rearranging gives $\frac{y}{x}=\frac{d}{x}-1$, therefore $\frac{x}{y}=\frac{1}{\varphi-1}$ which is equal to $\varphi$, which is I assume what you may have done. The rest then obviously follows.